# Адаптация слайдера

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощи сетки бутстрап, я могу адекватно настоить слайдер, чтобы он смотрелся как через экран компьютера [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Потому что, когда открываю через телефон Asus, то слайдер уезжает в правую сторону (также текст на нём смещается куда-то вечно, и вообщем вообще смотрится совсем не так, как через компьютер. ( у меня большой экран ).
Как я могу задать дополнительные стили, или что-то где-то изменить, чтобы на телефоне слайдер распологался по середине от меню, чтобы табличка с текстом была тоже читабельной...Надеюсь поняли меня. Спасибо..

```css
/*
    StyleSheet For Responsive Bootstrap Carousel Effect Ken Burns
    Author: Razboynik
    Author URI: http://filwebs.ru
    Description: Bootstrap Carousel Effect Ken Burns
*/
.kb_control_left,.kb_control_right
{
    top:50%;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:0;
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition:all ease-in-out .3s;
    transition:all ease-in-out .3s
}
.kb_wrapper:hover .kb_control_left,.kb_wrapper:hover .kb_control_right
{
    opacity:.8
}
.kb_icons
{
    line-height:50px;
    font-size:34px!important;
    font-weight:normal!important
}
.kb_control_left
{
    left:1%!important
}
.kb_control_right
{
    right:1%!important
}
.kb_elastic
{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
    transform:scale3d(1,1,1)
}
.kb_elastic .item
{
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0!important;
    display:block!important;
    -webkit-transform:scale3d(2,1,2);
    transform:scale3d(2,1,2);
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .7s ease-in-out 0s,opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    transition:transform .7s ease-in-out 0s,opacity ease-in-out .7s
}
.kb_elastic .item:first-child
{
    top:auto;
    position:relative
}
.kb_elastic .item.active
{
    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
    transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .7s ease-in-out 0s,opacity ease-in-out .7s;
    transition:transform .7s ease-in-out 0s,opacity ease-in-out .7s
}
.kb_wrapper
{
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    max-height:360px;
    max-width:100%;
    
}
.kb_wrapper>.carousel-inner>.item>img,.kb_wrapper>.carousel-inner>.item>a>img
{
    margin:auto;
    opacity:.8;
    width:100%!important;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -o-transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform-origin:100% 0;
    -webkit-animation:immortalkenburns 20000ms linear 0s infinite alternate;
    animation:immortalkenburns 20000ms linear 0s infinite alternate
}
    @-webkit-keyframes immortalkenburns
{
    0%
{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}
    100%
{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}

}
    @-moz-keyframes immortalkenburns
{
    0%
{
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}
    100%
{
    -moz-transform:scale(1.2);
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}

}
    @-ms-keyframes immortalkenburns
{
    0%
{
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transition:-ms-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}
    100%
{
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2);
    -ms-transition:-ms-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}

}
    @-o-keyframes immortalkenburns
{
    0%
{
    -o-transform:scale(1);
    -o-transition:-o-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}
    100%
{
    -o-transform:scale(1.2);
    -o-transition:-o-transform 20000ms linear 0s
}

}
    @keyframes immortalkenburns
{
    0%
{
    transform:scale(1);
    transition:transform 20000ms linear 0s
}
    100%
{
    transform:scale(1.2);
    transition:transform 20000ms linear 0s
}

}
.kb_caption
{
    left:57%;
    width:40%;
    bottom:50%;
    text-align:left;
}
.kb_caption_right
{
    left:3%;
    top:1%;
}
.kb_caption_center
{
    float:none;
    margin:auto;
    left:20%;
    top:3%;
}
.kb_caption h1
{
    font-size:37px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow:none;
    padding:5px 0 5px 15px;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    animation-delay:1s
}
.kb_caption h2
{
    font-size:20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow:none;
    padding-left:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s;
    animation-delay:1.5s
}
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px)
{
.kb_control_left,.kb_control_right
{
    border:0
}
.kb_icons
{
    font-size:18px!important
}
.kb_caption
{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    bottom:25%;
    text-align:center
}
.kb_caption h1
{
    font-size:22px
}
.kb_caption h2
{
    font-size:18px
}

}
    @media(min-width:481px) and (max-width:600px)
{
.kb_control_left,.kb_control_right
{
    border:0
}
.kb_caption
{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    bottom:25%;
    text-align:center
}

}
    @media(min-width:601px) and (max-width:767px)
{
.kb_caption
{
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    bottom:25%;
    text-align:center
}

}
    @media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px)
{
.kb_caption
{
    bottom:25%
}

}
    @media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px)
{
.kb_caption
{
    bottom:50%
}

}
.kb_wrapper
{
    background:#000
}
.kb_control_left,.kb_control_left:hover,.kb_control_left:active,.kb_control_left:focus,.kb_control_right,.kb_control_right:hover,.kb_control_right:active,.kb_control_right:focus
{
    color:#000;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background:#fff !important
}
.kb_caption h1
{
    color:#CCCCCC;
    background:#CC3300;
}
.kb_caption h2
{
    color:#FFF
}
    @media(max-width:600px)
{
.kb_control_left,.kb_control_left:hover,.kb_control_left:active,.kb_control_left:focus,.kb_control_right,.kb_control_right:hover,.kb_control_right:active,.kb_control_right:focus
{
    border:none!important;
    background:transparent!important
}

}
```

```html
 <div id="kb" class="carousel kb_elastic animate_text kb_wrapper" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000" data-pause="hover">

            
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/slider_01.jpg" alt="slider 01">
                    <div class="carousel-caption kb_caption">
                        <h1 data-animation="animated flipInX">У</h1>
                        <h2 data-animation="animated flipInX">Н.</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider_02.jpg" alt="slider 02">
                    <div class="carousel-caption kb_caption kb_caption_right">
                        <h1 data-animation="animated flipInX">Уе </h1>
                        <h2 data-animation="animated flipInX">Уп</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/slider_03.jpg" alt="slider 03" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption kb_caption kb_caption_center">
                        <h1 data-animation="animated flipInX">Сп</h1>
                        <h2 data-animation="animated flipInX">Бу</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            

            
            <a class="left carousel-control kb_control_left" href="#kb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-left kb_icons" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>

            
            <a class="right carousel-control kb_control_right" href="#kb" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-right kb_icons" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>

        </div>
        </div>
        < <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++ END BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL +++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
```

Comment: Приведите ссылку на проект (страницу, сайт). Ничего из кода не понятно.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko http://zont.spb.ru

Comment: у Вас же сайт не адаптирован, горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.
main и .container_12 имеют фиксированную ширину 960px.
Поэтому и слайдер центрируется по середине 960px.
Многое нужно доделывать.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko я это понимаю... просто это мой первый проект, и я всё с нуля изучал сам, поэтому многого не знаю, или не доделано еще. Могли бы вы дать советы? Хотя бы некоторые...
Про контейнер - Мне нужно уменьшить ширину, чтобы адекватнее смотрелся слайдер через устройства, помимо компьютера?

Comment: Если честно, сложно так объяснить. Вы не совсем правильно используете сетку бутстрапа. Например переделайте в main > .container > .row > .col-sm-4 ... , потому что сейчас у Вас .container > .main > .container_12 (??? для чего он тут ) > .wrapper (еще один не понятный блок) > .col-sm-4

Comment: Для img используйте класс img-responsive

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko спасибо вам. А еще вопрос один, вы писали, что слайдер у меня "ездит" , если через телефон заходить, потому, что он по середине ширины(960пх), а могу ли я задать ему место, чтобы он был в этом месте, при просмотре с любого устройства?

Comment: Адаптируйте и сделайте правильную структуру, тогда и слайдер будет там где нужно!